# Select from db, making icons from the items

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, linkbutton, imagebutton

What I'm trying to do is basicly what this photo shows.
[image]

When I select something from the treeview it passes a parameter to a linq command that selects some data from the database. For every item in the selection I want to make a Icon and a text that represents if the item is a folder or a file.
When I push the Icon or the Link i want it to do the same as i would push the treeview, pass a parameter to a linq command that selects again from the database and populates the placeholder.

The way I'm doing this now is to make at runtima a Panel that holds the ImageButton and LinkButton. Then i add the Panel to the ContentPlaceHolder.
The problem with this that it does it every time i select something new and also i cant get it to work if the push the icon or the linkbutton, only the from the treeview.

Could i use some controller and css to get this look for the Icons ?
Is there another better way ?

This is basicly the same system as the Explorer uses in Windows, Treeview shows only the folder but the window shows the folders and files. When i click a folder that folder opens up and the main window is populated with items that are inside that folder. If i click a file a editor opens up with the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry had to add as another Answer.  Here's a quick sample of the folder user control.

Create your Control... Format however you want.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FolderButton.ascx.cs" Inherits="FolderButton" %>
<div>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="yourfolder.jpg" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnTitle" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Add Properties and Click Event to the Code Behind (don't forget to fire the click event when your image and link buttons are clicked):

```
public partial class FolderButton : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int DatabaseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}  // you can even set your linkbutton text here. 

    public event EventHandler Click;
}
```

Create your Repeater of the FolderButton Controls:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptFolders" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptFolders_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:FolderButton ID="FolderButton1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Set Folder Id on DataBinding:

```
protected void rptFolders_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)        
{        
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)        
    {        
        Book book = (Book)e.Item.DataItem; //Or whatever your passing        

        FolderButton btnFolder = e.Item.FindControls("FolderButton1");

        btnFolder.Name=book.Name;
        btnFolder.DatabaseId=book.Id;

        btnFolder.Click += new EventHandler(FolderClicked);        
    }        
}
```

Lastly you can then do whever you want on the event Click:

```
     void FolderClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int id = ((FolderButton)sender).DatabaseId;

     /// Do something with your Id
}
```

Let me know if anything is unclear.  This is just a quick freehand sample, so forgive any typos or bad practices... code is just for demostration purposes only.

Comment: Ok, this looks good. But with this method it would always get the items again for each page right ? Now I'm just brainstorming, is there anyway to make the same query work for the treeview and the icon view ? Say port it to a virtual XML file and bind it somehow ? Or should i just selct the whole thing from the database and store it in the Session and just use that until someone changes the files then i would select the whole thing again.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at here, b/c I don't know your entire solution overall.  Depending on your requirements, you have many options.  Cache, Session, Sql Dependancy Cache, and on and on.  This all depends on how much your data changes among other factors( per user, application level data, etc.). Too many factors to name here.  Might want to start a new question.  Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand you question 100% but I think I got the gist.

I'm assuming that you want the folders first, then the files.  I would create two repeaters in this area, one to hold the Folder Image and link buttons, and the other for the file image and link buttons.

Break your linq command into two queries, one to get the folders and one for files.  Then just bind the repeaters to the corresponding repeaters.

Here's a bit of code to get you started:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFolders" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptFolders_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImage" runat="server" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLink" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And the code behind after calling `DataBind()`:

```
protected void rptFolders_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Book book = (Book)e.Item.DataItem; //Or whatever your passing

        ImageButton btnImage = e.Item.FindControl("btnImage");
        LinkButton btnLink = e.Item.FindControl("btnLink");

        btnLink.Text = book.Name;

        btnLink.Click += new EventHandler(FolderClicked);
        btnImage.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(FolderClicked);
    }
}
```

You can obviously do whatever you want with Click Events, just added those in for good measure.

I would probably create a Folder and File Control and use those instead of the imagebutton / linkbutton combo, this way I could store more information about the Folder / File to access them later without having to do another query to get the ID or what not.  But there are a million approaches to this, pick the one you think is best.

Let me know if you need more guidance w/ this solution, or if I didn't understand your question.

Happy Coding...

Comment: Yes, you did understand my problem exactly. I'm gonna try this code tomorrow. I think this is much better way then I'm doing it now.
What is this Folder and File control you are talking about, how could i implement that to my solution. Could i use that for both the treeview and the icon view ? The way I'm doing it now is basicly two querys for the same data, one for the treeview and move for the icons.

Comment: For the Folder and Image Controls, I would create a custom control, for each, that contain the imagebutton and linkbutton, formatted how you want. Then you could also add other properties on the control (ID for instance) if you wanted. Or even store the entire Book object inside the control.  Then just put these controls inside the repeaters. I'll try to create a quick sample, if you still need more help.

Comment: I think i understand what you are talking about but it would be awesome if you could make a example ;)